# Can Apache Trinidad Apps run on Tomcat 8?

Tags: tomcat, el, trinidad

We have a Apache Trinidad based app that runs fine with Tomcat 6 and 7. The same app throws the following exception on Tomcat 8. Trinidad lib version was 2.1.0 and MyFaces lib version was 2.1.16.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jspx at line 14

11:                 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/pervasync/images/pvs_logo_32_32.ico"/>
12:             </trh:head>
13:             <trh:body>
14:                 <tr:document title="...">
15:                     <head>
16:                         <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/pervasync/images/pvs_logo_32_32.png"/>
17:                     </head>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:113)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperty(UIXComponentELTag.java:297)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.core.CoreDocumentTag.setProperties(CoreDocumentTag.java:179)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperties(UIXComponentELTag.java:284)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentELTag.createComponent(UIComponentELTag.java:98)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.createComponent(UIXComponentELTag.java:223)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1195)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:514)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.doStartTag(UIXComponentELTag.java:113)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jspx._jspx_meth_tr_005fdocument_005f0(login_jspx.java:282)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jspx._jspx_meth_trh_005fbody_005f0(login_jspx.java:250)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jspx._jspx_meth_trh_005fhtml_005f0(login_jspx.java:175)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jspx._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(login_jspx.java:135)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jspx._jspService(login_jspx.java:96)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: What was the failed EL expression? Probably something is wrong there.

Comment: I suspected ELs too. So I removed all ELs but still got the same exception. The "title" attribute used to have an EL for its value. Seems the presence of the Trinidad tags would cause the exception. Wonder if anybody has had success running Trinidad with Tomcat 8.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @SimonArsenault This was a bug in Trinidad. I made a build from the latest on the 2.1.1 branch (trunk) and was able to see some pages. But there are other places that need similar fixes. Still waiting.

Comment: Thank you @Pervasync, I'll wait for the release and recheck.

Comment: @SimonArsenault I figured out how to build a working Trinidad 2.1.1 version. See [here](http://pervasync.wordpress.com/2014/10/19/how-to-checkout-and-build-apache-trinidad/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the bug [TRINIDAD-2483](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD-2483), which appears to be fixed in the upcoming 2.1.1 release.

Comment: I figured out how to build a working Trinidad 2.1.1 version. See [here](http://pervasync.wordpress.com/2014/10/19/how-to-checkout-and-build-apache-trinidad/).